# in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in line 45

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

In the error log of my server i´m getting the following PHP Warning:

in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in " /***/***..." on line 45.

In line 45 i have set a function that checks wether WooCommerce plug-in is active.

```
    /**
 * Construction function
 */
public function __construct() {
    // Check if Woocomerce plugin is actived
    if ( ! in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $this->new_duration = sober_get_option( 'product_newness' );

    $this->parse_query();
    $this->hooks();
}
```

Checking if it´s active with the if statement is necessary, is there anything i´m not seeing?

The error keeps popping up in my error log.

Comment: Does `apply_filters()` return an array?

Comment: @MarkusZeller It definitely does not

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi Thank you. Then it is clear. `in_array()` expects 2nd param as array.

Comment: array_filters() will return an array. Please check here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/ @Markus Zeller.

Comment: @sumoncse-sust It says mixed, not array. But in the OP's code a bool is returned.

Comment: mixed will be anythings( like bool, string, array ). i checked it (apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) and it returns an array of activate plugins. In OP code, i think bool return because of early call or not any active plugin. @ Markus Zeller

Comment: get_option( 'active_plugins' ) -- Replace with default empty array => get_option( 'active_plugins'  ,array() ) -- It's the correct WordPress way.

Comment: I did replace it the way that Markus suggested, using (array)apply_filters. Are both ways accepted ? I´m still waiting to see if this causes any more errors.. The log in the database takes some time until it updates...

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the method how you verify if a [plugin is available](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_plugin_active/).

```
if(!is_plugin_active('woocommerce/woocommerce.php')) {
    return;
}
```

Your method fails, because you check with `in_array()` which needs to have the 2nd parameter being an array, but `apply_filters()` returns a bool.

## Update

You could try to cast the result of `apply_filters()` being an array.

```php
if ( ! in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', (array)apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
   return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Markus, will be checking if the error persists, have added the code into the function. It just boggles me as i didn´t get this error before, feel like it happened after plug-in updates.. i´m not sure

Comment: I don't like function returning mixed. You can not rely on that when not verifying the result by yourself. So you could `$result = apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) );` and then evaluate if it is an array or not.

Comment: But if you want to check if an plugin is active, and there is exactly a function for testing that, it should be used.

Comment: I will be checking throught the day if the changes return any errors.. so many things to learn...

Comment: Old code had to be rewritten, after is_plugin_active was written, the error was PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_plugin_active() in *** It then proceeded to show me the stack race.

Comment: You could try to cast the result of `apply_filters()` being an array. See answer updated.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately now i´m having bigger problems and after the first code change i can´t edit again the code, i get the Something went wrong. Your change may not have been saved. Please try again. There is also a chance that you may need to manually fix and upload the file over FTP. error message

Comment: There are more ways to deploy. Using a repositiory, FTP/SFTP, SSH. The best way avoiding problems is using an IDE (or good editor like Visual Studio Code) capable with that.